# Storing abstract data in an abstract database system

Tags: java, database, abstract

I'm trying to write a simple library system in java. At the moment the implementation of the database is as follows: We have an abstract class that supplies an interface to the main code. And through inheritance we define a specific database logic. This is done so we can easily switch database systems (mySql, postgresql, etc).

Now here is my question the data we store is all in a class 'Book'. Instances of this class are passed along to the database, is it possible to make this an abstract class as well? So we can store DVD's or Phones without changing a lot.

We can't put the database code in the 'Article' class because we dont know what database system we are going to use. What we could do is take all the variables and put them in a single string and return this string to the database system and save that string. But this is not really something I would like to do.

So are there any other solutions I did not think of?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to solve a problem that has already been solved by modern ORM libraries, in particular the addition of JPA to the java specification.  I would recommend that you look into using this to implement your database strategy.

JPA is designed to allow you to persist objects and complex object hierarchies without you having to solve these particular problems yourself, since it soon become incredibly complex and wastes time you could be spending focusing on the logic of your app.

Hibernate would be a good starting point:

http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.2/

Comment: Thank you for the response and yes this definitely solves my problem. The thing is since i'm a student my goal was to solve the problem not make an app. Using a library is kind of cheating since I want to improve my programming skills but I will have a closer look at how these libraries where made and I'm sure I will learn a bunch from that!